# Uncanny dodge reduces damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

My friend is playing a level 10 barbarian, and our DM said that uncanny dodge reduces splash damage by 50% or something.

Does Uncanny Dodge reduce any damage somehow?
If it does, can you explain please?

Comment: Babarian+fighter

Answer (score 15):

Nothing from the description of [Uncanny Dodge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Uncanny-Dodge-Ex-) suggests that it would reduce damage.

> At 2nd level, a barbarian gains the ability to react to danger before her senses would normally allow her to do so. She cannot be caught flat-footed, nor does she lose her Dex bonus to AC if the attacker is invisible. She still loses her Dexterity bonus to armor class if immobilized. A barbarian with this ability can still lose her Dexterity bonus to armor class if an opponent successfully uses the feint action against her.
>
> If a barbarian already has uncanny dodge from a different class, she automatically gains improved uncanny dodge (see below) instead.

Your DM might be confused with [Improved Evasion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-advanced-talents/improved-evasion-ex), which *does* reduce damage from explosions and the like by 50%:

> Benefit: This works like evasion, except that while the rogue still takes no damage on a successful Reflex saving throw against attacks, she henceforth takes only half damage on a failed save. A helpless rogue does not gain the benefit of improved evasion.